# Componente VUE - ALTO 100% PANTALLA

Tags: vue.js

Tengo una vista donde agrupo dos layouts que siempre son visibles durante la navegación como lo son el header, el breadcrumb y el footer

```
 <template>
   <div>
     <div class="hidden">
       <navbar-component/>
       <breadcrumb-component style="margin-top:70px;"/>
   </div>
  <router-view style="margin-top:10px;"/>
 <footer-component style="width: 100%;margin-top:163px;" />
 </div>
</template>
```

El problema es que necesito que las vistas que renderizo luego en el router-view ocupen el 100% del alto de la pantalla, en vistas con poco contenido tengo resultados como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el footer queda con ese espacio por debajo.

Mi footer esta hecho de esta manera:

```
<template>
  <div class="card-body" style="background-color:rgb(40,50,113);">
        <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div class="col">
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: small;font-weight: bold;">
                   Sponsored by:
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255)">
                   Logo
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: xx-small">
                    © Copyright 2021. Todos los derechos reservados.
                  </p>
              </div>   
            
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: small;font-weight: bold;">
                   Servicio al cliente
                  </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: xx-small">
                   Contactanos
                  </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: xx-small">
                   111-111 2153
                  </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: xx-small">
                   info@correo.co
                  </p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: small;font-weight: bold;">
                   Información legal
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: xx-small">
                   Politica de protección de datos personales
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: xx-small">
                   Terminos y condiciones de uso
                  </p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: small;font-weight: bold;">
                   Politica de veracidad de la información
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: xx-small">
                   Protección al consumidor
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="font-size-sm mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);font-size: xx-small">
                   PQRS
                  </p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:white;">
            <img src="@/assets/images/logos/logo_sic.png" width="150">
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "FooterComponent",
}
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Y las vistas que reenderizo tienen esta estructura:

```
<template>
  <div class="center grid">
    <vs-row>
      <vs-col vs-type="flex" vs-justify="center" vs-align="center" w="4" offset="1">
        <vs-row justify="center" align="center">
          <vs-col vs-type="flex" vs-justify="center" vs-align="center" w="4">
            <vs-card type="5" style="width: 120px; heigth: 130px; margin: auto">
              <template #title>
                <h3 style="font-size: 9px">Crear proyectos</h3>
              </template>
              <template #img>
                <img
                  src="@/assets/images/icons/icon_add_project.svg"
                  alt=""
                  style="width: 90px"
                />
              </template>
              <template #text>
                <p style="font-size: 8px"></p>
              </template>
            </vs-card>
          </vs-col>
          <vs-col vs-type="flex" vs-justify="center" vs-align="center" w="4">
            <vs-card type="5" style="width: 120px; heigth: 130px; margin: auto">
              <template #title>
                <h3 style="font-size: 9px">Configurar proyectos</h3>
              </template>
              <template #img>
                <img
                  src="@/assets/images/icons/icon_create_project.svg"
                  alt=""
                  style="width: 90px"
                />
              </template>
              <template #text>
                <p style="font-size: 8px"></p>
              </template>
            </vs-card>
          </vs-col>
          <vs-col vs-type="flex" vs-justify="center" vs-align="center" w="4">
            <vs-card type="5" style="width: 120px; heigth: 130px; margin: auto">
              <template #title>
                <h3 style="font-size: 9px">Eliminar proyectos</h3>
              </template>
              <template #img>
                <img
                  src="@/assets/images/icons/icon_remove_project.svg"
                  alt=""
                  style="width: 90px"
                />
              </template>
              <template #text>
                <p style="font-size: 8px"></p>
              </template>
            </vs-card>
          </vs-col>
        </vs-row>
      </vs-col>
    </vs-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Lo siento, no se suficiente Vue para ayudarte. Lo mio es el HTML más bien y no sabria "traducir" todo eso a HTML, por eso te pedia el html final y css. Tampoco tengo claro que versión de bootstrap usa el vue-bootstrap, si está por la 4 o al 5. He borrado mi respuesta pues solo añadia ruido.

Comment: Ancla el footer para que siempre esté abajo, con position fixed o absolute